# How to set MaterialButton style programmatically in Material3 or Material You design

Tags: android, material-ui, material-design, material-you

As per new [material design 3](https://m3.material.io/libraries/mdc-android/getting-started), you can set the different button styles like:

[image]

Using below code in xml layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Elevated" />

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            style="@style/Widget.Material3.Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Filled" />
```

What I want is, I want to apply this Filled style of button when user press on button first time. So when user click on Elevated button, it should turn into Filled style button. Means, I want to apply the style programmatically from Java code in click listener of Elevated button. So anyone can help me please ?

I search much on that but what I found is, we can apply the style while creating Button itself programmatically in Java code and set the style. But I want to set only style at run time not entire button itself, otherwise I have to create button and perform add/remove button in java code.

Any help would be much more appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I found a way to solve it.
It's not as simple as it should be, but it works.

Here's what you can do:

1. First, create a custom attribute for your button:

```xml
<attr name="myButtonStyle" format="reference" />
```

2. Next, define the style you want to use, for example:

```xml
<item name="myButtonTextStyle">@style/Widget.Material3.Button.ElevatedButton</item>
```

3. Finally, you can use these to create the button programmatically:

```kotlin
val button = MaterialButton(context, null, R.attr.myButtonTextStyle)
button.text = "My Button"
```

I hope this helps!